# SQL Server IF statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement

I have two tables, with the following info:

```
Table1      Table2
--          --
ID#1        Item#1
ID#2        Item#1
            Item#2
```

If an ID# has more than one item, it compares the dates in the created_date column of Table2 and pick the Item# with the latest created_date.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: For starters, please post the tables definition. In your question, `Table2` doesn't have an `ID` nor a date. Also, what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Can you also please post what queries you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
select * from 
(
select row_number() over(partition by ID#1 order by created_date desc) as RN,
..
from Table1 Inner join table2 on ..
) A
Where RN = 1
```

Comment: Wouldn't you use TOP instead?

Comment: @PatB What if the OP wants to do it for more than one `ID#`

Answer (score 0):

You might find that `outer apply` is more efficient:

```
select t1.*, t2.itemid
from table1 t1 outer apply
     (select top 1 t2.*
      from table2 t2
      where t2.id1 = t1.id1
      order by t2.date desc
     ) t2;
```

In particular, this can make good use of an index on `table2(id1, date)` or `table2(id1, date, itemid)`.